# /dev/fb0 is the wrong resolution

Tags: raspbian, framebuffer

I noticed that when I plug my raspberry PI 3B+ into my monitor fbset reports this:

```
mode "1824x984"
    geometry 1824 984 1824 984 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,8/24
endmode
```

This is not the correct resolution, the correct resolution is 1920x1080. How can I get the raspberry PI to automatically detect the correct resolution without having to manually type is in manually somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely use a CEA mode. These include overscan borders, so the framebuffer resolution is smaller than the native resolution of the screen.

There's no way around setting the correct video mode manually if your monitor prefers such a mode. You may simply want to force a 1920x1080 DMT mode with HDMI audio. This can be done by setting

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
hdmi_drive=2
```

in /boot/config.txt. See [this page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md)  for a list of video modes (and other options). There are some alternatives, including creating an alternative edid file for your monitor, but the solution above is most simple.

Some older TV sets don't like DMT modes. You have to go with a CEA mode then and adjust the overscan border. You can do this by tweaking the

```
overscan_left=10
overscan_right=10
overscan_top=15
overscan_bottom=15
```

in /boot/config.txt. Negative values are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **Resolution** under **Advanced Options** in `raspi-config`.